# How can I use map2 and rename_with to modify nested column names?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to rename a set of columns in nested dataframes based on the values of an unnested column. Here is a simplified example of the dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_pre <- tribble(
  ~year, ~data,
  1970, tibble(GEOID_1970 = 1, TOTPOP_1970 = 2),
  1980, tibble(GEOID_1980 = 3, TOTPOP_1980 = 4)
)
```

Using `purrr`, I would like to rename the nested columns so that I have the following:

```
df_post <- tribble(
  ~year, ~data,
  1970, tibble(GEOID = 1, TOTPOP = 2),
  1980, tibble(GEOID = 3, TOTPOP = 4)
)
```

I've tried a variety of approaches, all of which throw some kind of error, e.g.:

```
library(purrr)
df_post <- df_pre %>% map2(.x = data, .y = year, 
                           ~ rename_with(str_replace,  
                                        pattern = paste0("_", .y), 
                                        replacement = ""))
#> Error: Can't convert a `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object to function
```

How can I use `map2` plus `rename_with` to modify the nested column names? In addition to solving this particular problem, I am also trying to gain more insight about how to pass arguments such as year to `map2` anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the `list` column 'data' with `map` and use `rename_with` selecting all the columns (`everything()`) while removing the suffix part from the column name with `str_remove`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df_new <- df_pre  %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
          rename_with(~ str_remove(., "_\\d+$"), everything())))
```

-checking

```
identical(df_new, df_post)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

If we want to make use of 'year' column with `map2`

```
df_new <- df_pre %>%
      mutate(data = map2(data, year, ~  {
              yr <- .y
              .x %>% rename_with(~ str_remove(., str_c("_", yr)), everything())
              }))
```

-checking

```
identical(df_new, df_post)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks so much. I'm trying to understand the general principle that requires assignment of .y within the anonymous function. Could you provide any additional insight?

Comment: @nicholas in your code, the columns are pulled outside the `mutate/summarise` so you may need `df_pre  %>% {map2(.x = .$data, .y = .$year, ~ .x)}`

Comment: This code (```df_pre  %>% {map2(.x = .$data, .y = .$year, ~ .x)}```) creates a list of two tibbles. I don't understand how it addresses my question about assignment. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: @nicholas I just wanted to show where your code in the beginning is not correct because it won't work with map2(data, year) because these objects are the columns in the data.frame

Comment: @akrun your solution here worked for me. Would you mind explaining two elements in more detail: 1) why are curly braces `{}` needed within the call of `mutate()`,  and  2) why is there a need for this assignment `yr <= .y`.

Comment: @DSH 1) `{}` is used when there are more than one expression.  here `yr <- .y` is one expression, and `.x %>% ..` is second expression.   2) The reason is that we are again using a lamda expression in `str_remove` which may or may not get the `.y` from the environment.  I haven't tested it but in some cases it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, so when you have two expressions with the curly braces, as in this example, the two appear on separate lines, but they are not separated by commas. Is that because everything within the curly braces is now its own environment and is not part of the global environment?

Comment: @DSH It could become complicated when you are doing something inside `across` within the `map`.  Thus, I assign it to a temporary object to avoid any issues.  Each newline is by default a new expression or if you want to write in a single line, use `;` as the end of expression i.e. `x1 <- 10;y1<- 20` etc